# Validation rule for months

Tags: validation

can anyone help me out with validation rule for months

**# At least 9 months or more from today**

> it should be like the input 5 Jan should get end of Oct 31,or the input of 10 Jan should get OCT 31 ,or any date in JAN will get me the end date 31 OCT

Comment: What sort of field is this on - date? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @DaveHumm Hi, let me explain you , Date field ,----- Today()+90  gives me 60 days from today but I need for months exactly i.e if today is JAN 5 I need feb ,march, april to added

Comment: Ok, so input 5 Jan should get 5 October.

Comment: @DaveHumm ,thank for staying in ,it should be like the input 5 Jan should get end of Oct 31,or the input of 10 Jan should get OCT 31 ,or any date in JAN will get me the end date 31 OCT .

Comment: Is this really a validation you need or a formula field to set the value as you seem to have a fixed date requirement which makes more sense as a formula?

Answer (score 1):

A simple formula that will do it is where I have 2 custom fields both of Date data type, Start_Date__c and Target_Test__c. You could change the <> to a >= to make it greater than or equal to the date.

```
Target_Test__c <> CASE( MONTH(Start_Date__c) , 
  1, DATE(YEAR(Start_Date__c),10,31) , 
  2, DATE(YEAR(Start_Date__c),11,30), 
  3, DATE(YEAR(Start_Date__c),12,31), 
  4, DATE(YEAR(Start_Date__c)+1,1,31), 
  5, DATE(YEAR(Start_Date__c)+1,02,28), 
  6, DATE(YEAR(Start_Date__c)+1,03,31), 
  7, DATE(YEAR(Start_Date__c)+1,04,30), 
  8, DATE(YEAR(Start_Date__c)+1,05,31), 
  9, DATE(YEAR(Start_Date__c)+1,06,30), 
 10, DATE(YEAR(Start_Date__c)+1,07,31), 
 11, DATE(YEAR(Start_Date__c)+1,08,31), 
 12, DATE(YEAR(Start_Date__c)+1,09,30), 
 DATE(YEAR(Start_Date__c),10,31))
```

If you need the Specific Date returned then I would think using a formula field with Date return type and the formula from 'CASE..' onwards would work better than manual entry.